# How have secondary routing inside Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routing setup for my application with a .  Everything is fine but one of my views loads a side bar which I want to use a different .  When I try to add additional routing to the component I get 'Child routes are not allowed for "xxx" use "..." on the parent's route path.

Has anybody added multiple layers of routing that can help?  thanks!

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), under **Parent Route Configuration**

Comment: Ultimately my issue was not having a  useAsDefault: true option on one of the routes in the other component.  thanks for the link Eric.

Answer (score 4):

Parent routes use a special `...` syntax

```
//parent route
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({path: '/', component: DemoPage, name: 'Home'}), 
    new Route({path: '/demo/...', component: DemoPage, name: 'Demo'})
})

//child routes defined in separate route config
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/spreadsheet', component: Spreadsheet, name: 'Spreadsheet' })
//etc   
])
```

I have a tutorial here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

You can also see nested routes in action here:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/spreadsheet

The left nav is using child routes.